# Does Google In App Review API Work With Capacitor?

Tags: reactjs, capacitor

Good evening all!

I currently have a web React JS (not native) application published as a TWA in the Google Play Store using PWA Builder.

I wanted to add in app review option but have found it is not available for a TWA.

Would the Google Review API work with capaitor?

Answer (score 0):

**Capacitor Rate App Plugin:**

Utilize the `@capacitor/rate-app` plugin to trigger the native platform's built-in app review dialogs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-rate-app

```
import { RateApp } from '@capacitor/rate-app';

const requestReview = async () => {
  await RateApp.requestReview();
};
```

there is another way
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/share

**Capacitor Native Sharing Plugin:**

- Leverage the `@capacitor/share` plugin to open the native app store
  review page on both Android and iOS platforms.
- Tailor the sharing message to encourage users to rate and review your app:

code :

```
import { Share } from '@capacitor/share';

const shareReviewURL = () => {
  // Replace with your app's Play Store or App Store URL
  const reviewURL = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.app.id';

  Share.share({
    title: 'Rate and Review Our App!',
    text: 'We value your feedback. Please leave a review to help us improve.',
    url: reviewURL,
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I look forward to trying this out!